# NGINX and Codeigniter: Uri does not work for index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

Hi,

I am a total newbie and now have set up a Server with nginx and codeigniter. Here is my nginx configuration file and it works to some extend. When I type in https://example.com/index.php, then I believe the index.php of codeigniter is found, because the default class of codeigniters routes.php is shown. But my problem is, when I attach an URI to the URL, it does not work, for example: https://example.com/index.php/myclass/myfunction.

I am not sure where to check? Is it an error in the nginx configuration or in the codeigniters index.php? But I did not change anything in index.php.

Is this here the right place to ask this kind of question or should I go somewhere else? I am totally stuck here and could not find any good tips in books or per google search.

Thanks for taking your time!

server {

```
listen       80;
server_name = example.com;
charset utf-8;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/weapp-access.log  main;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/log/weapp-error.log;

root /data/release/php-weapp-demo;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_uri;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}